# On Windows Phone 8 HTC, rotating a Bootstrap site from portrait to landscape creates a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the website: http://www.muddlingthru.ca/. We have ruled out the usual horizontal scroll-bar suspects.

Add meta tags.

```
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
```

Use the Bootstrap `div.container > div.row > div.col-md-*` structure.

Check for conflicting width/margin/padding/border settings in our CSS.

No luck.

We have also isolated when the problem happens:

- **only** if we rotate from portrait to landscape on WinPhone8
- not if we start in landscape on page load
- not if we do a page refresh *after* the problem happens
- not if we rotate using web developer tools in FireFox

If you have any ideas why this happens and how to fix it, please let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you applying the WP8 IE10 viewport fix recommended on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie10-width ?

CSS:

```
@-webkit-viewport   { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport      { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport        { width: device-width; }
@viewport           { width: device-width; }
```

JS:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
  var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style');
  msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode('@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'));
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```